# Will a Java SWT application for Windows run on Android?

Tags: android, swt

(Just beginning Android to day) I would like to know if an already written Java SWT application can run on Android ? I mean : is there an SWT layer specific for Android, that would allow an application alreday running on Windows with the SWT for Windows layer, to run also on Android ? The targeted platform is tablet (not telephone).

(I looked in the FAQ, but the 2 questions did not help me - people quote SWT but I did not understand why, sorry)

Comment: Unfortunately no, and although Android uses Java as a language for development, the paradigms in the Android stack are different that those of J2SE development

Answer (score 3):

> is there an SWT layer specific for Android, that would allow an application alreday running on Windows with the SWT for Windows layer, to run also on Android ?

No, sorry.

Comment: Well, that was unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was researching a way of writing UI that would work on both Android and Desktop. In my particular case, I was interested in developing a custom-paint view that could be rendered on a desktop using SWT, and using the Android Graphics library on an Android device.

My solution? Create stub classes that mimic the Android Graphics library and use SWT as the rendering engine.

I've put together a very crude prototype that demonstrates this:
https://github.com/davidair/android-swt-demo

I am not sure if this would help you in any way, because what you want is SWT on Android, not Android on Desktop, but perhaps you may find this idea useful.

P.S. I am Android novice, so this might not even make sense ;)

P.P.S. The only reason I developed this prototype was that the Android emulator is really slow...

Answer (score 0):

No. SWT has not been ported to Android yet. But there is a discussion today in the e4 mailing list about the possibility of JFace viewers: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/e4-dev/msg05191.html